# Why does vote-casting automatically upvote a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, badges, voting, vote-to-delete

A bit weird question here. I have noticed that upon my vote-cast to close a question due to a custom reason reported by another user, the same comment appearing in the comment section has been upvoted automatically without my awareness.

Here is a little-edited picture; I removed the usernames:

[image]

The red circle represents my vote has been cast. The red arrow points to the upvoted comment, which I am unable to cancel the upvote itself.

Why does it happen? I haven't seen this feature documented.

In this way, my close-vote helps the particular user get closer to the [`Pundit`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) badge - I feel cheated by the system! (A slight exaggeration.) This is not a right way to earn this badge.

I consider upvoting a good comment helping to find an answer or has an interesting point that should be also noted in an answer/question. But I'd not upvote a comment which just repeats what a close-vote says. Briefly said, I follow this scheme: *[Why upvote a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152846/why-upvote-a-comment)*

Comment: Tangential note: I kinda hate all those comments. The question is a duplicate several times over, so I've closed it as such. Now the next person with this particular assignment will have another set of keywords to point 'em to their solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The purpose of this - which will also happen if you vote to close a question as a duplicate when someone else has previously done so for the same target - is no more than this: **it improves the visibility of the comment**.

Observe that there are 6 comments below the question you just voted to close. By default, when the page is loaded only the first 5 are displayed; readers have to click the "*n* more comment(s)" link to see the rest. If the question was closed with the only explanation for closure being the 6th comment... Then it wouldn't be particularly obvious why the question was closed!

But if there are upvoted comments, those are displayed on page load even if there are older comments without as many votes. Thus by coupling an upvote for the comment with the vote to close, the system ensures visibility for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the reasons. My point is that since it's a generated comment, it should be treated as a generated comment as well -> ex. highlighted with a light-orange color or use another way than an upvote since it's coupled with the `Pundit` badge (and the `Commentator` badge as well). Or list the reason names and the number of votes inside the light-orange informational banner about the closure.

Comment: That's all a lot more work than just upvoting the comment. I'm not against it, but... kind of a lot of other stuff to do.